# How to look for a specific thing within a table with postgres/nodejs

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm currently using postgres, accessing it through a node server.

I'm feeling stuck on how I would search for a specific term within a table in order to make a change. I know I can SELECT certain items, but I don't know how to search within the items.

say my table is:

| animal | cuddly | scary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Medium Dog | yes | no |
| Small Dog | yes | no |
| Fluffy Dog | yes | no |
| Big Dog | yes | yes |
| Big Cat | no | yes |
| Small Fish | no | no |

Suddenly, I get bit by a dog, and now I want to change everything containing 'dog|Dog' to scary: yes.

I can't really find any good resources to create the function. Perhaps I've overlooked something.

Right now I'm using simple SELECT's like this:

```js
app.get('/update/:type', (req, res) => {
  pool.query("SELECT animal FROM petlist WHERE scary = 'no' AND animal = $1",[req.params.client],
   (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("I selected dog, but I can't see the specific types of dog!")
      throw error
      }
    console.log(results.rows);
    res.status(200).json(results.rows)
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Henry , apologies for putting it in a snippet box!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know your obscurification language (nodejs) but the Postgres predicate you are looking for would be either [ilike](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) or case conversion of the column `animal`. So

```
select animal 
  from petlist 
 where scary = 'no' 
   and animal ilike '%dog'; 

-- or if nodejs complains about ilike then 
select animal 
  from petlist 
 where scary = 'no' 
   and lower(animal) like '%dog';
```

so perhaps something like:

```
app.get('/update/:type', (req, res) => {
  pool.query("SELECT animal FROM petlist WHERE scary = 'no' AND animal ILIKE $1,[req.params.client],
   (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("I selected dog, but I can't see the specific types of dog!")
      throw error
      }
    console.log(results.rows);
    res.status(200).json(results.rows)
  })
});
```

with req.params.client is set to the string *%dog*.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks so much, I didn't know about ILIKE. It was a bit of a pain to get nodejs to pass the correct term with the apostrophes and percentage marks, but I got there eventually and it works perfectly. Thank you again!